# How to get detailed cause information from a CloudFormation "resource(s) failed to create" failure (AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalableTarget)

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-ecs

I have a constrained IAM user that I'm trying to get minimally permissioned to create the baseline ECS CloudFormation reference architecture cleanly:

https://github.com/aws-samples/ecs-refarch-cloudformation

However, I can't get the reference stack to deploy. I get this error:

```
“Embedded stack arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:*elided*:stack/icc-baselinestack-WebsiteService-*elided*/*elided* was not successfully created: The following resource(s) failed to create: [ServiceScalableTarget].”
```

I'm new to CloudFormation and I'm wondering how best to diagnose the cause. Is there a place where I can get more detailed diagnostic information about the cause of the problem?

FWIW I can deploy the reference architecture on a fully-permissioned private AWS account without any trouble as AWS intends with this reference stack.

For reference this is the section in service.yaml the error refers to:

```
    ServiceScalableTarget:
        Type: "AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalableTarget"
        Properties:
            MaxCapacity: !Ref MaxCount
            MinCapacity: !Ref DesiredCount
            ResourceId: !Join
                - /
                - - service
                  - !Ref Cluster
                  - !GetAtt Service.Name
            RoleARN: !Ref ECSServiceAutoScalingRoleARN
            ScalableDimension: ecs:service:DesiredCount
            ServiceNamespace: ecs
```

And this is my command line:

```
aws cloudformation create-stack --capabilities CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM --stack-name icc-baselinestack  --template-url https://s3.amazonaws.com/ecs-refarch-cloudformation/master.yaml
```

Comment: Side-note: You can create a role for the CloudFormation template that allows users (who have insufficient permissions to create the resources themselves) to launch the stack. Also, AWS Service Catalog can launch services via a CloudFormation stack even when a user does not have the required permissions themselves.

Comment: maybe you don't have access to "application-autoscaling:*"

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I do seem to have application-autoscaling:* and I will look at building a role for the launch and research AWS Service Catalog. I'm still curious if there would be a specific location where granular permission denial/autoscale failures are logged.

Comment: Did you ever figure out the issue?

Comment: I overcame the problem by setting up a role, but I never found a better way of obtaining granular policy/permissions decision-making logs.